# Django Rest Framework Serializer returns UItextfield instead of the actual value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I am using Django Rest framework for my APIs and was trying to create an API for the auth user model.
Here is my Serializer class

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = User
          exclude = ('password',)
```

My View class is as follows

```
class UserApiDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

and my url for the same is as follows

```
url(r'^user/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserApiDetailView.as_view()),
```

I am getting the following output on calling the API

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2015 18:54:04 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.10
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
{
    "date_joined": "2015-10-30T06:25:17.400955Z", 
    "email": "<UITextField: 0x7fee18f6fa10", 
    "first_name": "", 
    "groups": [], 
    "id": 2, 
    "is_active": true, 
    "is_staff": false, 
    "is_superuser": false, 
    "last_login": null, 
    "last_name": "", 
    "user_permissions": [], 
    "username": "<UITextField: 0x7fee18f69ad0"
}
```

Instead of getting the actual value for username and email, I'm getting UITextField: 0x7fee18f69ad0.
Am I missing something ?
Also, When I use ListAPIView, Everything gets works perfectly.

Comment: I haven't find anything related to `UITextField` in Python. Do you have it anywhere in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a theory. This is probably what's happening:

- Your API is being used by an iOS device.
- The iOS app is sending the `UITextField` object, serialized as string, instead of it's value.
- When you're viewing the data from your API, you are getting confused by the data since it looks like string representation of some Python object.

**Debugging The issue:**

Check the `username` and `password` field for that particular user in django admin or even better in database. That will help you find what's really in database.

Comment: I can't believe I spent so much time on this issue. Wow I feel really dumb at the moment. Thanks a lot for your help.